# Cogrowth and value of its series at the critical exponent

Tags: gr.group-theory, amenability, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and write $G = F/N$ for $N$ a normal subgroup of a free group $F$. Let $S_n$ be the elements in $F$ written as words of exactly $n$ letters. So, for $n\geq 1$, $|S_n|= 2k(2k-1)^{n-1}$ where $k$ is the number of generators of $F$. The cogrowth of $G$ is:
$$
\gamma = \limsup_{n \to \infty} |N \cap S_n|^{1/n} = \inf \lbrace \lambda >0 \mid \sum_{n \geq 0}  |N \cap S_n| \; \lambda^{-n} < +\infty \rbrace.
$$
What are (depending on properties of $G$, if it depends on this at all) the possible for $\sum_{n \geq 0}  |N \cap S_n| \; \gamma^{-n}$?

In particular, what if $G$ is amenable? (by Grigorchuk, $\gamma = 2k-1$ exactly when $G$ is amenable)

Comment: Edit: serie (French) replaced by series (English)

Comment: actually, "serie" is Italian, Romanian, Spanish or Swedish... French (or Portuguese) would be "série" ;oP  Thanks for the correction!